# \pdfminorversion cannot be changed after data is written to the PDF file

Tags: pdftex, inkscape

So I tried to make a figure through inkscape and attach it to a pdf file as suggested in this https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-2/ blog post. However, when I run the script to include the .pdf_tex image, the following error appeared (presented as written in the log file)

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stmaryrd/Ustmry.fd) [1
! pdfTeX error (setup): \pdfminorversion cannot be changed after data is writte
n to the PDF file.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.24 \maketitle
               {}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

I tried looking this error up on the internet, but the closest thing I can find is an error regarding PDF 1.4 that happened 6-7 years ago. I checked the original script and it included this file as required by the .pdf_tex so there shouldn't be any issues there. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Something is trying to set the version too late, but you don't show any code it is impossible to say where Ann's how it happens.

Comment: @daleif I've removed the `latexmk` tag, but it's clearly related to Inkscape since that's what's being used to generate the `.tex` code.